# Search access db using 3 fields

Tags: sql, .net, database, vb.net, ms-access

How can I search using 3 fields on vb.net
Usually we use something like:

```
Dim query As String = "Insert into () values () Where id=1"
```

I am not really good in access or sql, so I asked.
[image]
week, sow order and piglet# are different fields, because I need to segregate in the future if the user searches only on weeks.

What I want is, get the data which is the same as what the user inputs and display it in the DGV. Is something like this possible:

```
Dim query As String = "Insert into (FarrowDate) values (dtpFarrow.Text) Where week=1,soworder=1,pigletnumber=0"
' display the data in the DGV '
```

Help please, they only gave me a 2 week deadline >.<

Comment: "*What I want is, get the data..*", [SQL SELECT statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)? do you want to select/get data or update data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query you cannot use `where` in `insert` statement.Use `update` statement

```
Update tablename set FarrowDate='' where PigletNumber='0' And Week='1' And SowOrder='1'
```